# What are the implications of requiring SSL and a client certificate, but leaving anonymous authentication on in IIS

Tags: windows, ssl, iis, ssl-certificate

I have been configuring IIS to use a client certificate. I set this as REQUIRED. In my ASP.NET (WCF) service, a `<clientcertificate>` tag I used to specify the thumbprint of the client certificate that can use my service. Only that certificate should use my service.

In IIS, *anonymous authentication* is ENABLED. Other authentication methods are disabled. THe reason for this is that I get a `401.2 - Unauthorized` error if I keep it enabled. I tried to map things with `iisclientcertificatemappingauthentication` but could not get things to work yet. If you guys say that I am doing things wrong, I will change my question to see how I can get that mapping to work.

But for now, could there be an issue with keeping anonymous certification on and also requiring a client cert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I leave it on and DO NOT require iis client certificate mapping, any valid client certificate can be used to access the server.

I have now implemented IIS Client certificate mapping and mapped it to the user account of the PC. Then I changed the authorization rules so that only that user can access the physical path/website. Now other client certificates get denied access.